# How can i exit a loop in c++ if i press enter?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to exit a loop if press enter in codeblocks(c++).
So this is my code

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
    string s="";
    char ch;
    while(1)
    {
        cin>>ch;
        s+=ch;
    }
    cout<<s<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why? It can't work with loop like that, but it would work exactly how you want it with `std::cin >> s;` (unless there are spaces in your input, `std::getline()` will be your solution then).

Comment: If you're less interested in getting a line of text, and more interested in how to break out of a loop or block of code, you should use the 'break' statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is important when you can just get the entire string by using `getline()` or simply `std::cin()`, but here it goes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  std::string s = "";
  std::string ch;

  while(true) {
    std::cout << ">>> ";
    getline(std::cin, ch);

    if(ch.empty()) break;
    s += ch;
  }

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to print the string(s) also if i press enter

Comment: @IndrojitMondal just add a `std::cout << ch << std::endl` as the last line within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a general problem with `cin` in your use case! cin is always buffered because your console only passed inputs to your programm if "enter" was pressed. So you can't see the chars directly. If you want to get single characters as types from the user, you have to switch your console buffering off. This is not portable! My solution works on posix only. ( First part of example ) If there is no need to get the chars immediately, you do not need to switch of buffering, but in this case it really makes no sense to run your own loop over the single chars of input.

To break from a loop you simply can use the `break` statement, see code below.
But comparing against a single character value is also not portable as systems can give you `CR` or `CRLF` as two chars if enter is pressed.

```
void IoBufferOff()
{
    struct termios t;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t); //get the current terminal I/O structure
    t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; //Manipulate the flag bits to do what you want it to do
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &t); //Apply the new settings
}



int main()
{
    IoBufferOff();

    std::string s="";
    char ch;

    while(1)
    {
        std::cin.get(ch);
        if ( ch == 0x0a ) break;
        s+=ch;
    }

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you only want to read a single line from console which should be read if enter was pressed, you should use `getline` instead of using your own non portable solution!

```
int main()
{   
    std::string s="";
    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I want to print the string(s) also if i press enter